# Problem with close a "cart" of a javascript shop application

Tags: javascript

So basically, I have this shop applicattion, pure javascript, with a hidden div, that's work as a cart, whose content can be showed by pressing determined buttons and should be closed when a close cart button is pressed, becoming hidden again.
The problem is, the cart doesn't "close" when the button is pressed.
It doesn't show any error messages, or anything else in the console, and I already don't know what else to do.
Here is the HTML, CSS of the cart and the code of the buttons:

```
<div class="cart-overlay">
  <div class="cart">
    <span class="close-cart"><i class="fas fa-window-close"></i></span>
    <h2>Your cart</h2>
    <div class="cart-content">
      <div class="cart-item">          
        <div class="cart-footer">
          <h3>Total: $ <span class="cart-total">total</span></h3>
          <button class="clear-cart banner-btn">clear cart</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.cart-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(120, 120, 120, 120, 0.3);
  z-index: 2;
  visibility: hidden;
  }

.cart {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  z-index: 3;
  transition: var(--mainTransition);
  transform: translateX(100%);
  }

.showCart {
  transform: translateX(0);
  }

.transparentBcg {
  visibility: visible;
  }
```

The code of one of the buttons that shows the cart

```
let dbuttonsDOM = [];
dbuttons.forEach((dbutton) => {
  let id = dbutton.dataset.id;
  dbutton.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    let itemDesc = { ...Storage.getProduct(id) };
    this.displayItemDescription(itemDesc);
    this.showCart();
  });
});
```

The code of the button that should close the cart

```
const closeCartBtn = document.querySelector(".close-cart");
closeCartBtn.addEventListener("click", this.hideCart);
```

The functions that show and hide the cart

```
const cartDOM = document.querySelector(".cart");
const cartOverlay = document.querySelector(".cart-overlay");
showCart() {
  cartOverlay.classList.add("transparentBcg");
  cartDOM.classList.add("showCart");
}
hideCart() {
  cartOverlay.classList.remove("transparentBcg");
  cartDOM.classList.remove("showCart");
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the scope of `this` in your close cart button handler.  Try:

```
closeCartBtn.addEventListener("click", e => this.hideCart());
```